# Jodd Java - Can i hide WARN message on console?

Tags: java, jodd

My Program not error is perfect work but I feel annoyed from warning message.

So, I want to hide it from program console. What should I do?

(i can't edit html source code)

```
[Thread-4] WARN jodd.lagarto.dom.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Orphan closed tag ignored </meta> 
[Thread-3] WARN jodd.lagarto.dom.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Unclosed tag closed: <p>
```

Thanks for kindness.

Comment: Configure your logger for ERROR and up for the `jodd.lagarto.dom` package. We'd need to know which logger you're using to tell you exactly how, but it should be documented by the logger package.

Comment: Please explain or give examples for me, please.

Comment: What logger are you using?

Comment: I am novice programmer but i tried any way already. this my first time for logger on Java. Thanks for kindness.

Comment: anyone can hemp me T-T

Comment: Hey @Jaynova would you be so kind to mark the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Oh Yea!

I can find solution with myself. (Thank a lot Elliott Frisch for guide :) )

i use [Logback Library](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html)

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {

    final static Logger joddlogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("jodd");

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        joddlogger.setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.OFF);
        //do something...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is one correct answer, as @**Jaynova** and @**Elliott Frisch** said. **Jodd** uses Logback, so all you have to do is to mute the logging category in logback configuration, as explained in the other answer. You can do that from Java or from logback configuration file.

There is one more solution, added recently: `LagartoDOMBuilder` has a property `parsingErrorLogLevel`, which purpose is to set the log level of parsing errors (by default is set to `WARN`). Sometimes, its important to have these errors in the log (eg parsing your own code), and sometimes its just annoying (parsing live code, usually with lot of errors).

So while you can switch off the all logging for that package, you may also mute just the parsing errors by setting the level to `DEBUG` (assuming your global log level is higher).

So, in short, get the `LagartoDOMBuilder` instance before parsing and set this flag :)